# In Java, how do I use part of an array element to invoke a particular method?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I read a text file with 20 lines and assigned it to "tempsArray" A typical element of the array will look like this: "2014 Employee Doe, John 5000" I need to do a couple things with that data: I need to create a multi-dimensional array that has the year 2014 and 2015 as the initial dimension and then has the rest of the data as the second dimension i.e. `tempsArray[0][0]` would be "Employee Doe, John 5000" from the year 2014. There are 10 items in the file that are 2014 and 10 that are 2015. Next, I need to be able to use part of the second part of the array as a parameter in a method. For example; I need to use the 5000 in the above example as the parameter of `annualSalary()`. The code that I have for it so far is below:

```
public class TestEmployee {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String token = "";
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("employeeInfo.txt")).useDelimiter("\n"); //uses the 'new line' character as the delimiter, 

        List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            token = inFile.next();
            temps.add(token);
        }
        inFile.close();
        String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

        for (String s : tempsArray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }//end main

}//end TestEmployee
```

Comment: Use String.split() method for splitting the strings into array and then apply some logic.

Comment: Why not you can use MAP? with key as 2014 & 2015 and then store the value as a List or Array whatever fits for you.

Comment: @Sanket Makani They are already in an array. Does that mean I need to split the array itself into more arrays of smaller Strings? like tempsArray[0].String.split()?

Comment: Yes.@platypus87 Split it with " "(space) and take first element as initial dimension of array and last as salary.

Comment: Am I required to write a sample code for it?

Comment: @SanketMakani That would be helpful. I am trying it and I seem to have the syntax incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and replace your for loop with this one.

```
for (String s : tempsArray)
    {
        String splitted[]=s.split(" ");
        int first_element=Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]);//Use this for the dimension
        int salary=Integer.parseInt(splitted[splitted.length-1].trim());//Use this as argument of a method. Here .trim() is used to remove space if its present at the end of line
    }
```